# How to remove localhost:4200 url appending in [href] attribute in <a> tag in angular

Tags: angular, href, angular-dom-sanitizer

Below is the HTML:

```
 <a [href]= "message.messagelinkHere ? sanitize(message.messagelinkHere) : message.messagelink"
```

in ts file

```
 import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(public sanitizer:DomSanitizer) { }
 sanitize(url:string) {
  let sanitizedUrl;
  sanitizedUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)
  console.log(sanitizedUrl) //SafeValue must use [property]=binding:/(https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__nam11.safelinks)
  return sanitizedUrl;
 }
```

trying to hit the URL it gets appended with http://localhost:4200/https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__nam11.safelinks and link is opening the local application, instead of external site.

Can  you please let me know how can i remove localhost that is appended in href

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I did not use Dom sanitizer instead I directly kept URL using string interpolation to  tag.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xe5gzz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: i tried using without sanitizer as well, <a [href]= "message.messagelinkHere ? message.messagelinkHere : message.messagelink"
but i get that as  unsafe:(https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__nam11.safelinks......)

Comment: Did you see the example link I posted try putting your URL there.

Comment: if i use directly it works , but if i add the condition it wont work it says unsafe, i need to add the condition based on that i need to open different links as shown above

Comment: if we need to use that in class variable URL declared as global it will work, for some cases i get the URL on some method execution until then URL is not available, once the method is called and the URL is filled it turns out to be unsafe